# How does self-amplified spontaneous emission (SASE) work?

Tags: electromagnetism, laser, x-rays, laser-interaction, free-electron-lasers

Due to the new laser in Hamburg, the XFEL, the following question arised: How does self-amplified spontaneous emission (SASE) work?
There is an official article here http://www.xfel.eu/overview/how_does_it_work/ but unfortunately it's not sufficient for me. They only write that interaction among photons and electrons cause bunches of the latter ones so they will emit amplified. 
How does this interaction work? Why are some electrons accelerated and others slowed down?

[Scheme](http://pubs.rsc.org/services/images/RSCpubs.ePlatform.Service.FreeContent.ImageService.svc/ImageService/Articleimage/2010/CP/c003406a/c003406a-f1.gif)